# Strictly increasing chain of ideals in continuous functions on [0,1].

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ be the ring of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Is the following chain of ideals **strictly** increasing:

$(x)\subset (x,x^{1/2})\subset (x,x^{1/2},x^{1/3})\subset \cdots \subset (x,x^{1/2},\ldots ,x^{1/n})\subset\cdots$.

Comment: See whether this argument holds water: if $xf_1+x^{1/2}f_2+\cdots+x^{1/n}f_n=x^r$ for some $r$, $0<r<1/n$, then dividing through by $x^r$ gives a function on the left vanishing at $0$, but on the right the constant $1$, contradiction.

Comment: Are you simply trying to show the ring isn't Noetherian? Because there are easier candidates for ascending chains...

Comment: Any thoughts on the suggestions that have been posted, Cusp?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for the late reply. The comment was perfect and beautiful. If you could write it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $xf_1+x^{1/2}f_2+\cdots+x^{1/n}f_n=x^r$ for some $r$, $0<r<1/n$, then dividing through by $x^r$ gives a function on the left vanishing at zero, but on the right the constant $1$, contradiction.